# Copy listbox to another one

Tags: vba, ms-access, listbox, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to copy a `listbox` to another one

So I clear all items in the destination `listbox` like this

```
    While Forms!SalesCallInformation!lstMills.ListCount > 0
        Forms!SalesCallInformation!lstMills.RemoveItem (0)
    Wend
```

Then I copy all items like this

```
    For i = 0 To lstMillsToAdd.ListCount - 1
        Forms!SalesCallInformation!lstMills.AddItem (lstMillsToAdd.Column(0, i) & ";" &   lstMillsToAdd.Column(1, i) & ";" & lstMillsToAdd.Column(2, i))
    Next
```

The problem is that in the destination `listbox`, I still got the old items.
But when I set a watch on `Forms!SalesCallInformation!lstMills.ListCount` when I delete I can see that's it's decrementing so it must remove something.

Is it something with refreshing the form? Cause I tried after inserting the new items to do this: `Forms!SalesCallInformation.Refresh` but I have the same result.

Does anyone have an idea?

Thank you

Also, the `rowSourceType` is set to `value list`

Comment: Why do you not want to just copy the rowsource from one to the other?

Comment: well, when I wanted to delete at first, I tried `Forms!SalesCallInformation!lstMills.RowSource = ""` and it wasn't working so I thought it was impossible. I'm gonna try right now

Comment: @Remou I got the same result ie all the old data and the new one. So I will do it your way but I still have to fix this

Comment: Access, I assume? Doesn't it have a lstMills.Clear method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This example works for me:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click()
Me.List2.RowSource = Me.List0.RowSource
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click()
Me.List2.RowSource = ""
End Sub
```

Both listboxes are Value Lists. The Row Source is set to "abc";"def";"ghi"

Comment: Thank you! You made me realize that my save button was fine, so I found that in the close button I had a form.requery. And I cleaned my code at the same time doing it like you do.

Comment: I am glad you found the problem.